# dangling pointer, reason for value change after free()?

Tags: c, pointers, dangling-pointer

In the following code segment, after `free(x)`, why does `y` become 0?

As per my understanding, the memory in the heap that was being pointed to by `x`, and is still being pointed to by `y`, hasn't been allocated to someone else, so how can it change to 0?

And moreover, I don't think it is `free(x)` that changed it to 0.

Any comments?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int *y = NULL;
    int *x = NULL;

    x = malloc(4);
    *x = 5;

    y = x;
    printf("[%d]\n", *y); //prints 5

    free(x);

    printf("[%d]\n", *y); //why doesn't print 5?, prints 0 instead

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Solar flares. This is almost always because of solar flares.

Answer (score 12):

This is undefined behavior, explanations are just speculation.

I can speculate that maybe you are running a debug version of the C library, and that the debug version of free() does zero the pointed area.

Comment: +1, absolutely.  The question is actually meaningless because there is no defined answer.

Comment: Except that usually debug heap managers will explicitly fill freed memory with something *other than* zero.

Comment: @Cruachan - Not quite meaningless, the answer quite definitive, its undefined. Undefined is undefined.

Answer (score 4):

What is done in `free` depends on the implementation. It is not prohibited to zero out the memory after it's freed.

And what you're doing is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't **y** points to the same address as **x**, after line

y = x;

If you free **x**, you will also free the memory pointed by **y**.

If you are wondering why it prints '0', that undefined behavior, but I've seen it as a practice before, that some programmers, sets the freed area to '0'.

Download this video called ["Binky the pointer fun video"](http://www.cs.stanford.edu/cslibrary/PointerFunC.avi) (it's not a joke, actually is very educative), and you'll get pointers better.

Comment: I understand what are dangling pointers!, I was just trying to understand y=0 behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The call to `free()` will put the memory block that had been allocated by `malloc()` back onto data structures that the C runtime maintains for the heap (in this case something that might be called the 'free-list).

Manipulating the heap data structures might incidentally change what was being pointed to by `y` (since the program doesn't own the memory anymore, it has no reason to believe the memory shouldn't change).

In a non-debug build of the program, the runtime typically won't do anything specifically to invalidate freed memory, but as I mentioned, it may still make changes as a result of its own bookkeeping (though since the memory doesn't belong to the caller anymore, the runtime is allowed to do whatever it likes).

In a debug build, the runtime will probably explicitly overwrite the memory to a value that is likely to be invalid if the program does use it in the hopes that it will cause a problem that identifies the problem more readily. Usually the value used to overwrite the freed memory block isn't zero, since zero will often not expose a bug (i.e. NULL pointer checks will cause the code to 'handle' the invalid memory access). For example, MSVC's debug heap manager will overwrite freed memory with the value 0xDD (see [When and why will an OS initialise memory to 0xCD, 0xDD, etc. on malloc/free/new/delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370195/when-and-why-will-an-os-initialise-memory-to-0xcd-0xdd-etc-on-malloc-free-new/370362#370362) for more details).